# Find 3 integers a such that $ a\equiv 19^{10562}(mod\: 40320) $

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

I need to find three integer $ a\equiv 19^{10562}(mod\: 40320) $.  I know that I need to use Eulers Formula $a^{\phi (m)}\equiv 1(mod\: m)$.  I have determined that $\phi (m)=9216$.  So using this I think $19^{9216}\equiv 1(mod\, 40320)$.  Now I believe that gets me to the following.

$$19^{10562}\equiv 19^{9216}\cdot 19^{1346}(mod\, 40320)$$

But after this I am unsure where to go with this because I'm not sure how to address the $19^{1346}(mod\, 40320)$.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't know if I am correct, but I posted an answer.

Comment: Wait.... why the author deleted the question content? Can any moderator return it please?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if I am correct, but let's see... Supposing I am correct, this is very easy.

Notice that $19^{10562}$ itself would be congruent to itself in mod 40320. So will $19^{10562}+40320$, and so will all numbers $19^{10562}+40320n$ where $n$ is an integer...

Comment: This is a fine answer to the question as written.  I suspect that the poser intended that the smallest one be in the range $[0,40319]$ but why do the work?  If you need an explicit base $10$ representation, [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=19%5E10562) is happy to oblige if you click on More Digits enough.  +1

Comment: Sneaky, but accurate +1. I have written a solution to get low integers, but as Ross says, that wasn't asked for....

Answer (score 2):

The [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) $\lambda(40320)$ $=\lambda(2^7\cdot 3^2\cdot 5\cdot 7)$ $={\rm lcm}(\lambda(2^7), \lambda(3^2), \lambda(5), \lambda(7)) $ $={\rm lcm}(32, 6, 4, 6) =96$. So the value of $19^k\bmod 40320$ will cycle on a loop of length that divides $96$ and since $19$ is coprime to $40320$, we will have $19^{96}\equiv 1 \bmod 40320$.

Therefore $19^{10562} \equiv 19^{\large 10562 \bmod 96} \equiv 19^2\equiv 361 \bmod 40320.$ We can take e.g $k=0,1,2$ in $361+40320k$ to get three values as required.

Comment: Modulo arithmetic...the only branch of mathematics in which you can be off by $19^{10562}-361$ and still get the right answer. I waited myself to see an answer with integers closest to 0 as possible. +1

Comment: It's perfectly valid to evaluate $19^{1346} \bmod 40320$ also to get the correct answer. $2944$ isn't a valid possibility for any $19^k \bmod 40320$ so something else is wrong in your calculations.

Comment: OK so far, maybe not the easiest way but OK. However you do know that $19^{\large(1024+256+64+2)}$ $= 19^{\large 1024}\cdot 19^{\large 256}\cdot 19^{\large 64}\cdot 19^{\large 2}$, right?

Comment: I would take the modulo after every multiplication, but otherwise yes. What values do you have for those four exponents?

Comment: There's your problem - you should have $19^{1024}\equiv 19^{256}\equiv 19^{64} \equiv 34561$

Comment: $34561^2 = 1194462721$, you seem to be running out of precision.